# Распознавание речи и запись в текст

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи

Написал простую программу для распознавания речи на WinForms. Но мне необходимо заранее прописать то, что программа должна распознать. Как можно распознавать что угодно, не прописывая заранее в словарь? 
По нажатию кнопки включить запись и после все распознанные слова записать в предложение?
Мой код :

```
static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.82)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
        }

    }   

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        l = label1;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

        Choices numbers = new Choices();
        numbers.Add(new string[] {"один","два","три","четыре"});


        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Culture = ci;
        gb.Append(numbers);


        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно распознавать что угодно, не прописывая заранее в словарь?

С помощью [DictationGrammar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar?view=netframework-4.7.1)

```
    sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

    Grammar g = new DictationGrammar();
    sre.LoadGrammar(g);

    sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
```

Comment: Да, я это сделал, но в итоге, как выяснилось, на Windows 10 нету словаря на русском языке, лишь на английском и там качество не самое лучшее.

Comment: Вообще на виндовс 10 должен быть русский спич рекогнайзер, но, вероятнее всего, его нужно докачать как компонент в винду отдельно. Вроде как это делается в настройках установки языков и раскладок клавиатур по моей памяти.

Comment: Но если допустить что нет -- тогда используй онлайн распознавание от гугла.